# How to use purple correctly in my sentence

Tags: grammar, phrase-request, idiomatic-language

I would like to explain that there is a limited type of an object. For example, suppose that I have an object. Suppose further that the color of this object is very limited, for example, 2 colors only. Then, I would like to explain this object. I wonder how to explain that correctly.

*There is a limited color of this object.*

or

*There are limited colors of this object.*

Which one is correct, and why?

Comment: What’s purple here?

Comment: @Laurel. Sorry, the purple here is the type.

Comment: @Laurel. Really I do not know how to thank you. Your comment helps me a lot to understand how to build my sentence.

Comment: I can't understand this question, even with the explanation. If you feel that Laurel has enabled you to answer the question, then please write an [answer]. If not, please [edit] to show how you think "purple" might be used in a sentence. As it stands the question is unclear and needs to be closed.

Comment: @JamesK I edit my question.

Comment: Do you mean "There are only two purple objects." or "You can only have two purple objects." or "There are only two of the purple ones." or "There can only ever be two purple ones." or "This only comes in a few colors, including purple."...?

Comment: I think you're asking about colours. If an article comes in only two colours, say exactly that "Long socks come in two colours". If only one colour is left then say "available (only) in purple". Have I understood the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to state that a particular object is only available in two different colors.

Of your two suggestions, your second is best:

> There are limited colors of this object.

A better way to express it may be:

> This object comes in limited colors.

or

> There are limited colour options for this object.

This assumes you do not want to state how many colors are available. If you did, then why not say:

> This object comes in a choice of 2 colors.

Or

> This object has a limited choice of 2 colors.